# Geocode is throwing an error in android. Trying to build a cab booking app

Tags: android, geocode

This is a user app cab booking system in android, Geocode throwing the error.
Only thing I get is Unable to get location please try again...

I am not able to understand the code fully as I a beginner, I got this code to debug from my manager. Please help

Google API are enabled and API key is working fine.
**Please Help**

````
     * Fetch Location from address if Geocode available get from geocode otherwise get location from google
     */
    fun fetchLocation(addresss: String, type: String) {
        getAddress = addresss

        object : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            var locations: String = ""


            override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): String? {


                if (Geocoder.isPresent())
                // Check geo code available or not
                {
                    try {
                        println("Geocoder.isPresent")
                        val geocoder = Geocoder(applicationContext, Locale.getDefault())
                        val address: List<Address>?

                        // May throw an IOException
                        address = geocoder.getFromLocationName(getAddress, 5)
                        if (address == null) {
                            return null
                        }
                        val location = address[0]

                        countrys = address[0].countryName

                        if (isPickup) {
                            if ("" != countrys)
                                pickipCountry = getAddress

                        } else {
                            destCountry = getAddress

                            if ("" == destCountry)
                                destCountry = pickipCountry

                        }
                        location.latitude
                        location.longitude

                        lat = location.latitude.toString()
                        log = location.longitude.toString()
                        locations = "$lat,$log"
                    } catch (ignored: Exception) {
                        ignored.printStackTrace()
                        // after a while, Geocoder start to throw "Service not available" exception. really weird since it was working before (same device, same Android version etc..
                    }

                }
                return if (locations != null)
                // i.e., Geocoder succeed
                {
                    locations
                } else
                // i.e., Geocoder failed
                {
                    fetchLocationUsingGoogleMap() // If geocode not available or location null call google API
                }
            }

            // Geocoder failed :-(
            // Our B Plan : Google Map
            private fun fetchLocationUsingGoogleMap(): String? {
                println("fetchLocationUsingGoogleMap")
                getAddress = getAddress.replace(" ".toRegex(), "%20")
                val googleMapUrl = ("https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + getAddress + "&sensor=false"
                        + "&key=" + sessionManager.googleMapKey)

                println("GoogleMapUrl ${googleMapUrl}")
                try {
                    val googleMapResponse = JSONObject(ANDROID_HTTP_CLIENT.execute(HttpGet(googleMapUrl),
                            BasicResponseHandler()))

                    // many nested loops.. not great -> use expression instead
                    // loop among all results

                    if (googleMapResponse.length() > 0) {
                        val longitute = (googleMapResponse.get("results") as JSONArray).getJSONObject(0)
                                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                                .getString("lng")

                        val latitude = (googleMapResponse.get("results") as JSONArray).getJSONObject(0)
                                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                                .getString("lat")

                        val len = (googleMapResponse.get("results") as JSONArray).getJSONObject(0)
                                .getJSONArray("address_components").length()
                        for (i in 0 until len) {
                            if ((googleMapResponse.get("results") as JSONArray).getJSONObject(0)
                                            .getJSONArray("address_components").getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("types").getString(0) == "country") {
                                countrys = (googleMapResponse.get("results") as JSONArray).getJSONObject(0)
                                        .getJSONArray("address_components").getJSONObject(i).getString("long_name")

                            }
                        }

                        if (isPickup) {
                            if ("" != countrys)
                                pickipCountry = countrys

                        } else {
                            destCountry = countrys

                        }
                        return "$latitude,$longitute"
                    } else {
                        return null
                    }

                } catch (ignored: Exception) {
                    ignored.printStackTrace()
                }

                return null
            }

            override fun onPostExecute(location: String?) {
                if (location != null) {
                    try{
                        val parts = location.split(",".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
                        val lat = java.lang.Double.valueOf(parts[0])
                        val lng = java.lang.Double.valueOf(parts[1])
                        val latLng = LatLng(lat, lng)

                        if ("homeclick" == type) {
                            if (isPickup) {
                                Constants.changedPickupLatlng = latLng
                                markerPoints.set(0, latLng)
                                pickupaddress.setText(getAddress)
                                homeClick()

                            } else {
                                markerPoints.set(1, latLng)
                                destadddress.setText(getAddress)
                                homeClick()
                            }
                        } else if ("workclick" == type) {
                            if (isPickup) {
                                Constants.changedPickupLatlng = latLng
                                markerPoints.set(0, latLng)
                                pickupaddress.setText(getAddress)
                                workClick()

                            } else {
                                markerPoints.set(1, latLng)
                                destadddress.setText(getAddress)
                                workClick()
                            }

                        } else if ("searchitemclick" == type) {
                            if ("" == countrys)
                                countrys = pickipCountry

                            searchItemClick(latLng, countrys)
                        }
                    }catch (e: Exception){
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }

                } else {
                    commonMethods.showMessage(this@PlaceSearchActivity, dialog, "Unable to get location please try again...")
                    commonMethods.hideProgressDialog()
                }
            }
        }.execute()
    }```
````

Comment: Do you have location on?  Do you have wifi on?  Did you request location permissions at runtime and in the manifest?  It sounds like either it can't reach the network or it can't use the location service.

Comment: Also, using code you don't fully understand as a beginner is never a good idea-  you don't know what it's doing, you don't know what the negative side effects are, and you don't know if it's even doing what you hope it will.  That's a good point to stop and try to understand it, rather than plowing ahead.